# How to detect Makefile re-evaluation due to include

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile (GNU `make`) which will re-evaluate itself under certain circumstances due to an `include`. I would like to be able to determine, during evaluation and before rule execution, whether this is the first "pass" or the second "pass" (the re-evaluation). Is there a way to do this?

I have tried exporting a variable, but this does not seem to work (it seems the re-evaluation is not treated as a sub-make, which I guess makes sense).

I am working on reformulating the Makefile to remove the re-evaluation but it's not simple for my application and I was hoping for a short-term fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about the fact that make restart itself if any included files (with `include`) has been remade during the first attempt ? If so, you're looking for the [MAKE_RESTARTS](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKE_005fRESTARTS-_0028number-of-times-make-has-restarted_0029) special variable, which (quoting the manual) `will contain the number of times this instance has restarted`

Comment: Yes I am talking about that! Thank you, I just didn't know the right words to look for.